# Redis Cluster data migration in two differnt Kubernetes Clusters

Tags: kubernetes, redis, redis-cluster

Is there anyway we can migrate Redis Cluster data that are running inside 2 different Kubernetes cluster? How we can communicate between Redis stateful pods which are running on two different Kubernetes Clusters?

We have two Redis Clusters which are running on two different Kubernetes Clusters X & Y. I want to transfer data from redis-X to redis-Y cluster. How we can establish connection between redis-X and redis-Y clusters so that we can migrate data?

Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: Checkout this tool: https://github.com/vipshop/redis-migrate-tool

Comment: How you will run this tool inside Kubernetes cluster? we have private IP range on two different Kubernetes cluster. How will you create connection between both Redis Cluster which is running inside two different Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible approaches to establish connection between clusters:

1. Built-in solutions
2. 3rd party solution

#### Built-in solutions

- [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) - Exposes the service on each Node’s IP at a static port (the `NodePort`). A `ClusterIP` service, to which the `NodePort` service routes, is automatically created. You’ll be able to contact the `NodePort` service, from outside the cluster, by requesting `<NodeIP>`:`<NodePort>`
- [`LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) - Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider’s load balancer. `NodePort` and `ClusterIP` services, to which the external load balancer routes, are automatically created.
- [`ingress`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) (both 1st and 3rd party implementations) - more flexible then previous two, but only works with HTTP/HTTPS.

Read more: [Kubernets services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/), [NGINX ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)

#### 3rd party solution

[Istio](https://istio.io/latest/) supports [multi-cluster deployment](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/deployment-models/#multiple-clusters) model. However, if you don't have service mesh deployed, doing so may be too much for single task use.

---

Once you have connection established between clusters you can migrate Redis using [`MIGRATE`](https://redis.io/commands/migrate) command, or [`redis-migrate-tool`](https://github.com/vipshop/redis-migrate-tool) proposed in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new approach using Skupper.

https://github.com/bryonbaker/rhai-redis-demo

It is a full step by step demo I wrote that shows a globally distributed real-time replicated cache from on-premises and across four kubernetes clusters. The Redis cache is replicated from on-premises to Sydney, London and and New York.

No  NodePorts, Submariner, or Istio Federation required. It all uses standard routes.

The demo is based on OpenShift - but it will work with any flavour of xKS.